# Problems create multidimensional array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array, local-storage

I'm trying to save some data in localstorage. My script looks like this:

```
    localStorage.clear(); //only for testing

    if(typeof localStorage.akten == "undefined") {
        localStorage.akten = new Array();
    }

    var nam = "alpha";


    localStorage.akten[nam] = {
        "beta": 12
    };

    localStorage["a_akte"] = nam;
```

But if I do `console.log(localStorage);` or `console.log(localStorage.akten);` `akten` is only an empty string? Why? With an normal object instead of localStorage it works well.

Comment: JavaScript `Array` accepts only numerical indices. When you convert your array to JSON, the serialization will not include your arbitrary named properties (e.g. `alpha`). You should use an `Object` instead. And you can use literals (e.g. `{}` for `Object` and `[]` for `Array`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage#localStorage) is not an *Object*; it's an interface. You can only assign a *String* to it, and the best way to do so is with [`localStorage.setItem`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-setitem). If you want to be setting more complex data, you'll need to encode it as [*JSON*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) first.

```
function localStore(key, obj) {
    return window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function localGet(key) {
    return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
}

localStore('foo', {bar: 'baz'});
localGet('foo'); // Object {bar: "baz"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Suprisingly the devil is in the details. `localStorage` only stores strings. Encode your objects as JSON before depositing them there using for example `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.